# Nano drone propeller keep flying off

Tags: propellers, beginner

I got my son a drone for his birthday but less than 24 hours and one of its propellers got lost 3 times and because it’s a nano drone. It is hard to find. I was hoping to find a solution here. Attached the drone photo. It is nano drone by Red5
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

if the friction fit propellers fall off that's for either of two reasons, either they are a bit too loose, which can be fixed with a tiny slice of paper to fill up the mount hole.

the other reason of course is they fly off when crashing or when slamming into something, and with friction fit there isn't much you can do, other than crash less.

Comment: What the best advice for someone who is new to flying so obviously they gonna hit walls and crash.

Comment: I wouldnt suggest to start indoors unless you have the space - having even a toy drone smash in someone's face or get entangled in someones hair is unpleasant in the best case, and can lead to injury.  A good way of training are simulators, but the radio of a toy likely doesn't work as a usb joystick so the only thing that can be done is practice practice and practice more