# Drone back propellers not lifting it up

Tags: propellers, toy-grade-drone, repairs

This is a second toy drone I got my son because I do not want to spend fortune on a DJI drone if controlling in an issue. It was fine but lately it hasn’t been lifting up. As you can see from picture, 2 propeller (I think 1 is throwing air upwards). But why? I tried to take off the propeller but it wasn’t helpful.

Why is it happening?

[image]
[image]

Comment: This feels like a defective product, could you please confirm that at least one of the propellers is pushing air up and that you're doing nothing but raising the throttle? If you aren't moving anything on the controller, there is no good reason why a propeller should be directed upward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause is that the propellers have been swapped.

Drones have two types of propellers, for clockwise and anti-clockwise rotation. These must be fitted in diagonally-opposite pairs.

If you have a right-hand propeller where a left-hand propeller should be, it will blow upwards and force that corner of the drone downwards.

You get the same effect if the motor is reversed, but that is harder to fix.

Comment: Great knowledge, I will check that. What I did was to check if the number on the blades are facing up, like A1,B1 but didn't know they r made such to be anticlockwise and clockwise.

Comment: I can confirm that fixed the issue, those were also mentioned on back on manual. Since I changed the propellers, I have issue of [propellers flying off](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/2803/nano-drone-propeller-keep-flying-off/2806#2806)